# Rails button_to - applying css class to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb, button-to

This is silly, but I just can't figure out how to style the input element created by Rails `button_to` -- and yes, I've read the docs over and over again and tried the samples.

Here's my ERB code:

```
 <%= button_to "Claim", action: "claim", idea_id: idea.id, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-small'  %>
```

And this yield the following HTML:

```
<form action="/ideas/claim?class=btn+btn-small&amp;idea_id=4&amp;remote=true" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input data-remote="true" type="submit" value="Claim">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="pU3umgqrDx3WbalfNK10c9H5B5N4OzPpohs4bWW8mow=">
  </div>
</form>
```

Whereas all I want is just `input` to have `class = "btn btn-small"`.

Help? Thank you!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The signature of the method [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) is

```
button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

So use `{}` to distinguish `options` and `html_options`

```
<%= button_to "Claim", {action: "claim", idea_id: idea.id, remote: true}, {class: 'btn btn-small'} %>
```

Answer (score 26):

`<%= button_to "Claim", {action: "claim", idea_id: idea.id, remote: true}, {form_class: 'form', class: 'btn btn-small'} %>`

form_class: class for the form

class     : class for button in the form