# Adding classes to rails button_to helper

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a class to a button generated with rails button_to helper, but I cannot find a consistent answer to the question of how to incorporate the class into the declaration. I have:

```
 <%= button_to("Logout", session_url, method: :delete, class:'waves-effect waves-light btn-large') %>
```

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123884/rails-button-to-applying-css-class-to-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<%= button_to("Logout", session_url, method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-success") %>
```

**This works fine for me**

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the "html options" from the "make the button_to" options - ie make two separate hashes eg:

```
<%= button_to("Logout", session_url, {method: :delete}, {class:'waves-effect waves-light btn-large'}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= button_to　"Logout", session_url, method: :delete, form_class:"waves-effect waves-light btn-large" %>
```