# Customizing button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How might I add CSS to this:

```
<h9>Sunday</h9>
    <% @sunday.each do |chorelist| %><br>
    <p2><%= chorelist.name %></p2>
    <%= button_to "Delete", chorelists_destroy_path(id: chorelist.id), 
        class:"btn btn-space" %>
    <% end %>
```

I'm not sure where I could add a div class or button class. (I'm still relatively new to Rails.)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails button\_to - applying css class to button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123884/rails-button-to-applying-css-class-to-button)

Comment: what you try to implement in it?

Comment: you may want to try inspecting the button in your browser to see what are the elements of the button that you can access with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your_file.html.erb ,

```
<style>
  // do ur styling.
</style>
```

Or under assets/stylesheet add new file your_file.css write style in it and don't forget to include this file in application.css